# Rake file with Jenkins (Cucumber, watir-webdriver)

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, rake, watir-webdriver

I've started with watir and cucumber a while ago and have been trying to run my project with Jenkins. I have a watir Project (watir,cucumber) in C:\project_name. I have rake file in the project also and when I run it in CMD everything goes ok and tests are succesfully executed --> C:\project_name>rake

Rakefile I'm running looks like this.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber/rake/task'

Cucumber::Rake::Task.new(:features) do |t|
     t.profile = 'default'
end

task :default => :features
```

I have tried to execute Rake file with Jenkins but unable to make it work. So far what I have done with Jenkins (Running in localhost:8080)

1) Plugins installed eg. cucumber-reports, Jenkins Rake plugin

2) Tried to add New job --> Build a free-style software project

I really don't have idea how to make Rake file to work with Jenkins. I was hoping to get these nice reports (cucumber-reporting) available through Jenkins.

If someone can help me with this it would be more than perfect.

Comment: we're running  cukes via jenkins here..  let me ask the fellow who configures that stuff for the setup he is using.  not sure if we are using rake, we might just be invoking cucumber directly

Comment: Whats the error your getting from jenkins? is it able to run any rake tasks? from what you are saying it could be one of a couple of things. Do you have the ruby plug in installed in to jenkins? Also if jenkins is on a windows server, has the user it is running under been set up access to ruby in the users (or system) path. I know when installing jenkins to a windows server it creates a jenkins user by default which can confuse things slightly if you dont know that.